# Mutation isn't observing and logging to console

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have the following script that runs on page load. It's meant to observe every `td` element on the page and check if it changes.

I was just logging the mutation to console to see my next steps, as I want to see what values change in each `td` element (the div refreshes every 15 seconds that houses the table).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    /** Change URL */
    setInterval(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8888/profitmanager/wp-content/plugins/football-stats/update.php'
        }).done(function(){
            $('.fbs_results').load(
                location.href+" .fbs_results>*", function(){
                    var hidden = [];
                    $.each(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("table_state")), function(index, value) {
                        if(value == 'hidden'){
                            $('tr[data-index="'+index+'"]').hide();
                        }

                    });

                    // console.log(hidden);
                    $('tr').each(function(index){

                    });
                }
            );
        });
    }, 15000);

    const config = {
      characterData: true,
      characterDataOldValue: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    };

    function tdChanges(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        console.log(mutation);
        // if (mutation.addedNodes.value) {
        //  console.log();
        // }
      });
    }

    const tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    Array.from(tds).forEach(function(td) {
        const observer = new MutationObserver(tdChanges);
        observer.observe(td, config);
    });

});
```

But it doesn't work, nothing logs. Weird.

Can anyone fix my code?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

`querySelector()` returns only a single Element. To look at all of them you need to use `querySelectorAll()` then loop over the result:

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
Array.from(tds).forEach(function(td) {
  const observer = new MutationObserver(tdChanges);
  observer.observe(td, config);
});
```

Here's a working example in a [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/u7a02L8q/), as the SO snippet editor is sandboxed and has issues running MutationObservers.

One thing to note here is that MutationObservers are not fast, and if you have a lot of `td` elements in your page you may see a performance hit. You may be better served by placing a single MutationObserver on the parent `table` and letting the event bubble up, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/eo7unrsq/).

Comment: Awesome man, thank you. I'll test this now. How could I perform an action if the value has changed of the `td`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, as `td` elements do not have a value. Do you mean the text within the `td`?

Comment: My bad. Indeed, the text.

Comment: I'm having a hard time implementing the above into what I've already got. See my updated question please dude.

Comment: You've put the MutationObserver initialisation in to the `tdChanges()` function, which is supposed to handle the change events. The initialisation needs to be outside of that. See the fiddle link in the answer above for a complete example.

Comment: I've updated again. It's not logging anything. I've also included the div refresh script.

Comment: I would guess from the context of the code that the AJAX request is removing/adding `tr` and `td` cells. As such the observers are destroyed when the `td` are removed. You need to add new observers when you create the new rows in the HTML. That being said, if you have access to the data which is creating the HTML content then the MutationObserver is redundant; just read from the AJAX response directly.

Comment: I see what you're saying, however, the only problem is, the table itself is being generated in PHP reading a JSON file, decoding the JSON to a PHP Array and foreaching each row.

Comment: Literally, the whole point of this code is to check if there is a new value in the `td` every 15 seconds, compared to the previous - and then, flash yellow for 5 seconds. It seems like a shambles so far.

Comment: In which case I'd suggest you change how this works. Return JSON from PHP and have your JS build the HTML on the client side. Then you completely remove the need for the MutationObserver at all (and frankly they are a last resort and shouldn't be used unless absolutely necessary)

Comment: In addition, making an AJAX request every N seconds is also not a great idea. I'd suggest looking in to WebSockets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198130/discussion-between-jake-and-rory-mccrossan).